# Weatherproofing metal

Tags: metal, metalworking, varnish

I have some large galvanized metal disks that I going to grind into an outdoor decoration.

Grinding will destroy the zinc covering.  It'll be painted afterwards.

How can I weatherproof the metal?

Comment: Be careful when grinding zinc. To protect workers, OSHA has set an average legal limit of 1 mg for zinc chloride fumes and 5 mg for zinc oxide (dusts and fumes) in workplace air during an 8 hour workday, 40 hour work week.https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/phs/phs.asp?id=300&tid=54

Comment: Thanks @DavidD.  I'll only be doing a little bit and outdoors but I'll wear a respirator anyway.

Answer (score 2):

i've been decorating some metal mailboxes which have been outdoors for 1.5 years and are still looking good.

### the process

- i started by removing old paint/lacquer that was about to fall off. i did this by mounting a [wire wheel brush](https://www.amazon.com/metal-brush-drill/s?k=metal+brush+drill) on my drill and brushing the mailbox.
- next, i cleaned the mailbox with [white spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spirit) followed by cleaning it in water and drying it.
- i applied several layers of [molotow](https://www.molotow.com/en/) spray paint.
- i used molotow actrylic pens for drawing illustrations on top.
- finally, i applied three layers of [clear spray paint](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=clear+spray+paint&t=ffab&iax=images&ia=images) for outdoor use.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You said that you will be painting the ground galvanized metal.  If you use outdoor **weatherproof** paint, then you will be weatherproofing your material for the length of time indicated in the tin.

Comment: As there are so many formulations around, perhaps a paint especially designed for use on metal outdoors would be worth considering? Especially if you are near the sea. 

Look for something designed for metal fence or a steel corrugated roof. Some paints also have anti rust-chemicals added. I'd talk to the people at the paint desk.

Remember that these often come in a spray can for small jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are grinding galvanized metal, for "final finishing" I quickly found 5-10 methods on YouTube and Instructables that give some relatively easy solutions.  "How to galvanize metal" was my search string.

I've been investigating electroplating steel. aka de-rustification.

Galvanizing is an interesting anti-rust technique. Most galvanizing is hot dipped, in a vat of molten zinc.

But using a zinc anode, zinc oxide electrolyte, and a steel item = electroplating (OUTSIDE - allow H2 gas to escape & not explode) is quite easy. No super nasty chemicals needed either.  Happy re-surfing (researching) and investigating

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of paint, it should form an able enough barrier. Fun fact, to prevent the rusting of large, steel, salty sea-faring boats, they connect large blocks of zinc to teh hull on the inside. The zinc "protects" the outer steel layer by basically transferring the corrosion to it (there's a lot more chemistry involved but that's basically what happens).